# while starting oracle instance we facing LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 problems

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, I have set log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\TSH1' parameter and shutdown the database. When I tried to start up the db., I got the following error:

SQL> startup
ORA-16024: parameter LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 cannot be parsed

Does anyone have any ideas of how I might fix this?

Comment: The path cannot have spaces.